# Getting custom posts by post id from cutomizer text input

Tags: theme-development, customization

I want's to show custom posts in a page by using post id which is taken from customizer text input
my code is here

```
<?php
    $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'post__in' => array( get_theme_mod('fp_post') ) ) );

    while ($query -> have_posts()) : $query -> the_post();
        the_title();

    endwhile;
?>
```

where **fp_post** is the customizer setting name.

when use this code its show only one post but when use **179,182,185** (post id number) in place of **get_theme_mod('fp_post')**  its show all  of posts

when print the value of **fp_post** it show **179,182,185**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `post__in` parameter needs an array, see the [WP_Query docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters).

With your customizer field you are not saving an array, you are saving a comma separated string. So try something like this:

```
$my_field = get_theme_mod('fp_post');

// create an array from comma separated values
$the_post_id_array = explode(',', $my_field);

$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'post__in' => $the_post_id_array ) );

while ($query -> have_posts()) : $query -> the_post();

    the_title();

endwhile;
```

See in the docs:

```
'post__not_in' => array( '1,2,3' )  // <--- this wont work
```